# What's wrong with this handler? JS

Tags: javascript, html-table

I need the text to be changed only in the selected
cell. The first time all is well. When I try in another cell, the text also changes as it should, but at the same time in the previous one too, and so on.

```js
//change text
var changeText = function(e) {
  var inputChangeText, applyChanges, blockTd;
  inputChangeText = document.getElementById('changeText');
  applyChanges = document.getElementById('applyToChanges');

  inputChangeText.value = e.target.textContent;

  applyChanges.addEventListener('click', function() {
    e.target.textContent = inputChangeText.value;
  }, false);
}

//allow to change
function eventsInTable() {
  var checkBoxChanges = document.getElementById('changes');
  var table = document.getElementById('tableCinema');

  if (checkBoxChanges.checked) {
    table.addEventListener('click', changeText, false);
  } else {
    table.removeEventListener('click', changeText, false);
    alert("You haven't access to change");
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="tableCinema">
  <tr>
    <th>Type</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>*</td>
    <td>*</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Change: <input id="changes" type="checkbox" name="" onclick="eventsInTable()"><br> Get text for change: <input id="changeText" type="text" name="" value="">

<button id="applyToChanges">Apply</button>
```

Comment: You keep adding listeners to the `Apply` button, but never remove the old listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `changeText()` you add another listener, and they all run when you click the `Apply` button.

Instead of adding a listener in `changeText()`, just set a global variable to the element that needs to be changed.

```js
var targetElement;

var inputChangeText = document.getElementById('changeText');

var applyChanges = document.getElementById('applyToChanges');
applyChanges.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (targetElement) {
    targetElement.textContent = inputChangeText.value;
  }
}, false);

//change text
var changeText = function(e) {
  inputChangeText.value = e.target.textContent;
  targetElement = e.target;
}
//allow to change
function eventsInTable() {
  var checkBoxChanges = document.getElementById('changes');
  var table = document.getElementById('tableCinema');

  if (checkBoxChanges.checked) {
    table.addEventListener('click', changeText, false);
  } else {
    table.removeEventListener('click', changeText, false);
    alert("You haven't access to change");
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="tableCinema">
  <tr>
    <th>Type</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>*</td>
    <td>*</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Change: <input id="changes" type="checkbox" name="" onclick="eventsInTable()"><br> Get text for change: <input id="changeText" type="text" name="" value="">

<button id="applyToChanges">Apply</button>
```

Comment: Thanks It works. I also wanted to write this code via a global variable, but is it a good option to use the global variable? I taught that they should be used only in those cases when they are really needed. Is it possible to write without them? Much need to add code for this?

Comment: You could put all the code inside an IIFE, and then the variable can be limited to the scope of the IIFE instead of being global. What's important is that it's outside the individual functions, in a scope that they share.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('#changeText');
var button = document.querySelector('#applyToChanges');
var table = document.querySelectorAll('table tr td');

var tobechanged = null; // remembers which td was last clicked
for(i=0;i<table.length;i++){ // adds onclicked event for every td element
  table[i].onclick = function(){ 
    tobechanged = this; 
    input.value = this.innerHTML; 
  }
}

button.onclick = function(){
  tobechanged.innerHTML = input.value; // make changes to innerhtml of last td clicked.
}
```

```css
table td{
border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="tableCinema">
    <tr>
        <th >Type</th>
    </tr>                   
    <tr>
        <td >1</td><td >*</td><td >*</td>
    </tr>                   
</table>

Get text for change: <input id="changeText" type="text" name="" value="">

<button id="applyToChanges">Apply</button>
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong in the original, and how you fixed it.

Comment: Why loop through the table looking for the index when you can just put the element itself in the `tobechanged` variable?

Comment: @Barmar I don't know either, but it is fixed now. Didn't post any explanation because your comment was correct. Will provide explanation next time. Thanks.